# Is it possible to display a local video on mouseover in D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, tooltip, mouseover

http://s2.postimg.org/z6su9cl4p/screen.jpg

The idea is when the user takes the pointer to a square, a particular video should be played. The video will be stored locally. The source of the location of the boxes is an excel, it would be great if the src for the video can be the same excel/CSV file.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WryBqM

```
d3.csv("SainaMarinFullMatch.csv", function(data) {


 data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.sepalLength = +d.sepalLength;
    d.sepalWidth = +d.sepalWidth;
    d.rally = +d.rally;
    d.Player = d.Player;
    d.Player2 = d.Player2;
    d.AssistWinX - +d.AssistWinX;
    d.AssistWinY = d.AssistWinY;
    d.Source = +d.Source;
    d.Destination = +d.Destination;
  });


    // style the circles, set their locations based on data
        var rects =
    groups.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "circles")
      .attr({
        x: function(d) { return x(+d.sepalWidth); },
        y: function(d) { return y(+d.sepalLength); },
        width: 18,
        height: 17,
       // r: 10,
        id: function(d) { return d.Player ;}
      })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        if (d.Result == "Win") {return "LawnGreen"}  // Not checking the If function.
        else if (d.Result =="Loss") { return "Red" }  
        else if (d.Result =="Assist") { return "#c3d7df" }
            else {return "#f2f2f2"}
        ;})
    .style("opacity", function(d) {
        if (d.rally < 0.25) {return 0.5}  // Not checking the If function.
        else if (d.rally > 0.25 && d.rally <= 0.5) { return 0.75 }  
        else {return 1}
        ;})
        .attr("data-legend",function(d) { return d.Result}) // Trying to add legend

        ;

    // what to do when we mouse over a bubble
    var mouseOn = function() { 
        var rect = d3.select(this)

    // transition to increase size/opacity of bubble
        .transition()
        .attr({
        x: function(d) { return x(+d.sepalWidth); },
        y: function(d) { return y(+d.sepalLength); },   
        width: 28,
        height: 28,
       // r: 10,
        id: function(d) { return d.Player ;}
      })
        .ease("elastic")
        .duration(800).style("opacity", 1)

        //.size(function(d) {return ("r");})
        ;


        // append lines to bubbles that will be used to show the precise data points.
        // translate their location based on margins
    //  svg.append("svg")
    //      .attr("class", "guide")
    //  .append("line")
    //      .attr("x1", +rect.attr("x"))
    //      .attr("x2", 3) // If i hardcode values here it works
    //      .attr("y1", +rect.attr("y"))
    //      .attr("y2", 26) // If i hardcode values here it works
    //      .attr("transform", "translate(17, 38)") // Need to check this
    //      .attr("stroke", "Red")
    //      .attr("stroke-width", 2)

    // function to move mouseover item to front of SVG stage, in case
    // another bubble overlaps it
        d3.selection.prototype.moveToFront = function() { 
          return this.each(function() { 
            this.parentNode.appendChild(this); 
          }); 
        };

    // skip this functionality for IE9, which doesn't like it
        if (!$.browser.msie) {
            rect.moveToFront(); 
            };
          };


    // what happens when we leave a bubble?
    var mouseOff = function() {
        var rect = d3.select(this);

        // go back to original size and opacity
        rect.transition()
        .duration(800)
        .style("opacity", function(d) {
        if (d.rally < 0.25) {return 0.5}  // Not checking the If function.
        else if (d.rally > 0.25 && d.rally <= 0.5) { return 0.75 }  
        else {return 1}
       ;})
        .attr({
        x: function(d) { return x(+d.sepalWidth); },
        y: function(d) { return y(+d.sepalLength); },
        width: 18,
        height: 17,
       // r: 10,
        id: function(d) { return d.Player ;}
      })
        .ease("elastic")

        ;

        // fade out guide lines, then remove them
        d3.selectAll(".guide").transition().duration(100).styleTween("opacity", 
                        function() { return d3.interpolate(.5, 0); })
            .remove()
    };

    // run the mouseon/out functions
    rects.on("mouseover", mouseOn);
    rects.on("mouseout", mouseOff);

    // tooltips (using jQuery plugin tipsy)
    rects.append("title")
            .text(function(d) { return d.Result + " by " + d.Player + ". " + "Last Shot Played:" + d.Shot +". " + "Total No.of Rallies:" + d.RallyLength; }) // Need to change the data to text box
    $(".rects").tipsy({ gravity: 's',});
```